# document.addEventListener("keydown",myFunction) is not working

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a game, and I'd like to use "w", "a", "s" and "d" keys for movement, but it isn't working here is my code.

```
let yAxis=0;
let xAxis=0;

let test=document.getElementById("testDiv");
document.addEventListener("keydown",myFunction)




function myFunction(event){
    let k=event.key
    if(k=="s"){
        
            test.style.top=yAxis +"px";
            yAxis+=1;
        
    }else if(k=="d"){
            test.style.left=xAxis +"px";
            xAxis+=1;


    }else if(k=="a"){
       
            test.style.left=xAxis +"px";
             xAxis-=1;
        
        
    }else if(k="w"){
       
            test.style.top=yAxis +"px";
            yAxis-=1
        


        
    }else{
        document.getElementById("testY").innerText="Use 'w','s','a' and 'd'. "
    }
}
```

I expect my div to move up when pressing the 'w' key, down when pressing 's', right when pressing 'd' and left when pressing 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues.

1. is you must set the [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) properties of your elements particularly the movable element which should be set to `absolute`.
2. `} else if (k = "w") {` won't work properly - you're *assigning* `w` to `k` not checking to see if `k` *equals* `w`. You have it right for the other conditions, just not that one.

You may also find [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) easier to navigate that a series of `if/else` statements, and moving the code that changes the axes values to before the statement that updates the position of the element.

Note: I'm using increments of 10 rather than 1 in this example.

```js
let yAxis = 10;
let xAxis = 10;

const test = document.getElementById('testDiv');
const message = document.getElementById('message');

document.addEventListener('keydown', myFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
  
  switch(event.key) {

    case 'w': {
      yAxis -= 10;
      test.style.top = `${yAxis}px`;
      break;
    }

    case 'd': {
      xAxis += 10;
      test.style.left = `${xAxis}px`;
      break;
    }

    case 's': {
      yAxis += 10;
      test.style.top = `${yAxis}px`;
      break;
    }

    case 'a': {
      xAxis -= 10;
      test.style.left = `${xAxis}px`;
      break;
    }

    default: {
      message.textContent = `Use 'w','s','a' and 'd'.`;    
      break;
    }

  };
  
}
```

```css
#container { height: 200px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid darkgray; position: relative; }
#testDiv { height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: blue; position: absolute; top: 10; left: 10; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="testDiv"></div>
</div>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @TheJunkmania.c I figured it out and updated my answer (see point 2).

Comment: thanks,,,i had set the position property on my element,,,seems the issue was the increemention,,,but if statement is slower than the switch case,,,do you know why?

Comment: I'm using increments of 10 rather than 1 in my example just so I could test it better.